# Why am I getting *** Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001c8a000 *** from insert function?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap, priority-queue, heap-corruption

So I am getting this error statement (after my program completely compiles and runs through main properly) when implementing a minimum priority queue using a Binary Heap. After debugging I believe that I found it is being caused by my insert function, or more specifically the

> push_back(element)

line in my insert function in BinaryHeap.cpp.

I'm under the impression that this error is caused from a heap overflow, but I am using a vector to implement my heap (which worked when just using ints rather than the struct items) so it should/is allocating memory as needed. Could somebody explain to me why I am getting this weird error statement and how to fix it? Thank you

Here is my two header files and my main file, as well as the full error statement

BinaryHeap.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
struct EmptyHeap : std::range_error {
      explicit EmptyHeap(char const* msg=NULL): range_error(msg) {}
    };

struct data {
   int jobID;
   int length;
   int priority;
};

struct item {
   int value; //Priority 
   int key;
};

/*
 * Class Declaration
 */
class BinaryHeap
{
private:
   vector <item> v1;
   int left(int parent);
   int right(int parent);
   int parent(int child);
   void heapifyup(int index);
   void heapifydown(int index);
public:
   BinaryHeap() {}
   ~BinaryHeap();
   bool is_empty();
   void insert(item element);
   void remove_min();
   item findMin();
   void print();
   int length();
};

BinaryHeap::~BinaryHeap() //DONE
{   
while (!is_empty())
    v1.pop_back();

}

bool BinaryHeap::is_empty() { //DONE
    if (v1.size() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


/*
 * Return Heap Size
 */

int BinaryHeap::length() //DONE
{
    return v1.size();
}

/*
 * Insert Element into a Heap
 */
void BinaryHeap::insert(item element) //DONE
{
    v1.push_back(element); //The error is coming from this
    heapifyup(v1.size()-1);
}
/*
 * Delete Minimum Element
 */
void BinaryHeap::remove_min() //DONE
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        throw EmptyHeap("Empty Heap");
    }
    cout << "Element Deleted: " << "(" << v1[0].key <<"," << v1[0].value << ") " << endl;
    v1[0] = v1.at(v1.size() - 1);
    v1.pop_back();
    heapifydown(0);
}

/*
 * Extract Minimum Element
 */
item BinaryHeap::findMin() //DONE
{
    if (is_empty())
        throw EmptyHeap("Empty Heap");
    else
        return v1.front();
}

/*
 * Display Heap
 */
void BinaryHeap::print() //DONE
{
    int pos = 0;
    cout<<"Heap (Key, Value) -->  ";
    for (int pos = 0; pos < v1.size(); pos++) {
        cout<< "(" << v1[pos].key <<"," << v1[pos].value << ") ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

/*
 * Return Left Child
 */
int BinaryHeap::left(int parent)
{
    int l = 2 * parent + 1;
    if (l < v1.size())
        return l;
    else
        return -1;
}

/*
 * Return Right Child
 */
int BinaryHeap::right(int parent)
{
    int r = 2 * parent + 2;
    if (r < v1.size())
        return r;
    else
        return -1;
}

/*
 * Return Parent
 */
int BinaryHeap::parent(int child)
{
    int p = (child - 1)/2;
    if (child == 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return p;
}

/*
 * Heapify- Maintain Heap Structure bottom up
 */
void BinaryHeap::heapifyup(int in) //in = index DONE I BELIEVE
{
    if (in >= 0 && parent(in) >= 0 && v1[parent(in)].key > v1[in].key)
    {
        item temp = v1[in];
        v1[in] = v1[parent(in)];
        v1[parent(in)] = temp;
        heapifyup(parent(in));
    }
}

/*
 * Heapify- Maintain Heap Structure top down
 */
void BinaryHeap::heapifydown(int in) //in = index DONE I BELIEVE
{
    int child = left(in);
    int child1 = right(in);
    if (child >= 0 && child1 >= 0 && v1[child].key > v1[child1].key)
    {
       child = child1;
    }
    if (child > 0 && v1[in].key > v1[child].key)
    {
        item temp = v1[in];
        v1[in] = v1[child];
        v1[child] = temp;
        heapifydown(child);
    }
}

vector<data> readData(string fileName)
{
    ifstream ist;
    ist.open(fileName.c_str());
    if (!ist) {
        cerr << "Error in opening the file" << std::endl;
    }
    vector<data> datas;
    vector<data> tempdatas;

    char delim = ',';
    string line;

    while(getline(ist,line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string str;
        data temp;
        int i = 0;
        int dataNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            getline(ss,str,delim);
            dataNum = atoi(str.c_str()); //Convert String to int
            if (i == 0) {
                temp.jobID = dataNum;
                }
            else if (i == 1) {
                temp.length = dataNum;
                }
            else {
                temp.priority = dataNum;
            }
        }
        tempdatas.push_back(temp);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < tempdatas.size();j++) {
        datas.push_back(tempdatas[j]);
    }

    return datas;
}


vector<item> dataToItems(vector<data> datas, string type)
{
    vector<item> items;
    for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++) {
        if (type == "jobID") {
            item temp;
            temp.value = datas[i].jobID;
            temp.key = datas[i].priority;
            items.push_back(temp);
        }
        else if (type == "length"){
            item temp;
            temp.value = datas[i].length;
            temp.key = datas[i].priority;
            items.push_back(temp);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Not a possible type" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

MinPriorityQueue.h

```
#include "BinaryHeap.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct EmptyMinPriorityQueue : std::range_error {
  explicit EmptyMinPriorityQueue(char const* msg=NULL): range_error(msg) {}
};

class MinPriorityQueue {
private:
    BinaryHeap bh;
public:
    MinPriorityQueue() : bh() { } // constructor FIX
    ~MinPriorityQueue() { bh.~BinaryHeap(); } // destructor
    bool isEmpty() {return bh.is_empty();} //tests if P is empty
    void insertItem(item kx); //inserts a key k and value x into P
    int size() {return bh.length();}
    item minElement() {return bh.findMin();} //returns an entry with the smallest key in P
    void removeMin(); //removes an entry with the smallest key in P
    int minKey() {return bh.findMin().key;} //returns the smallest key in P
    void print();

};

void MinPriorityQueue::insertItem(item kx) {
    bh.insert(kx);
}

void MinPriorityQueue::removeMin() {
    bh.remove_min();
}

void MinPriorityQueue::print() {
    bh.print();
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "MinPriorityQueue.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() { //It is only ordered/sorted in the sense that the first element is the least, the rest are "ordered" when needed.
    MinPriorityQueue MPQ;

    vector<data> DataSetSize10 = readData("DataSetSize10.csv"); //Working on descen10 file
    vector<item> ItemSetSize10 = dataToItems(DataSetSize10, "jobID");

    vector<item> test;
    cout << "Insert all JobID Data into Binary Heap from DataSetSize10.csv" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < ItemSetSize10.size(); i++) {
        MPQ.insertItem(ItemSetSize10[i]); //This is causing my error
    }
    MPQ.print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Remove min and print new MPQ" << endl;
    MPQ.removeMin();
    MPQ.print();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What gets printed (including the error statement)

```
Insert all JobID Data into Binary Heap from DataSetSize10.csv
Heap (Key, Value) -->  (-16,2) (-3,9) (-16,4) (-3,10) (8,7) (15,6) (-3,8) (11,1) (3,3) (11,5)

Remove min and print new MPQ
Element Deleted: (-16,2)
Heap (Key, Value) -->  (-16,4) (-3,9) (-3,8) (-3,10) (8,7) (15,6) (11,5) (11,1) (3,3)

*** Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001f54000 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7ab54)[0x7f7304512b54]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c8c2)[0x7f73045148c2]
./a.out[0x403830]
./a.out[0x40326c]
./a.out[0x402a8b]
./a.out[0x402667]
./a.out[0x401707]
./a.out[0x40260a]
./a.out[0x4023ea]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f73044b9c05]
./a.out[0x401609]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00407000 r-xp 00000000 00:39 148951836                          /home/ugrads/r/reid_jordan8/CSCE221/PA5/Phase2/a.out
00606000-00607000 r--p 00006000 00:39 148951836                          /home/ugrads/r/reid_jordan8/CSCE221/PA5/Phase2/a.out
00607000-00608000 rw-p 00007000 00:39 148951836                          /home/ugrads/r/reid_jordan8/CSCE221/PA5/Phase2/a.out
01f54000-01f75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f7300000000-7f7300021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7300021000-7f7304000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7304498000-7f7304650000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 268570647                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f7304650000-7f7304850000 ---p 001b8000 fd:03 268570647                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f7304850000-7f7304854000 r--p 001b8000 fd:03 268570647                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f7304854000-7f7304856000 rw-p 001bc000 fd:03 268570647                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f7304856000-7f730485b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7304860000-7f7304875000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 269333731                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f7304875000-7f7304a74000 ---p 00015000 fd:03 269333731                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f7304a74000-7f7304a75000 r--p 00014000 fd:03 269333731                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f7304a75000-7f7304a76000 rw-p 00015000 fd:03 269333731                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f7304a78000-7f7304b79000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 269333747                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f7304b79000-7f7304d78000 ---p 00101000 fd:03 269333747                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f7304d78000-7f7304d79000 r--p 00100000 fd:03 269333747                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f7304d79000-7f7304d7a000 rw-p 00101000 fd:03 269333747                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f7304d80000-7f7304e69000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 268438548                  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f7304e69000-7f7305069000 ---p 000e9000 fd:03 268438548                  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f7305069000-7f7305071000 r--p 000e9000 fd:03 268438548                  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f7305071000-7f7305073000 rw-p 000f1000 fd:03 268438548                  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f7305073000-7f7305088000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7305088000-7f73050a9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 268437504                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f7305293000-7f7305298000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f73052a6000-7f73052a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f73052a9000-7f73052aa000 r--p 00021000 fd:03 268437504                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f73052aa000-7f73052ab000 rw-p 00022000 fd:03 268437504                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f73052ab000-7f73052ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffd7df35000-7ffd7df56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd7dfd8000-7ffd7dfda000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Comment: I will not debug your program.

Comment: Could you at least give me some insight? As in part 1 (As one could consider the primary part of my question) why am I getting this error statement? What issue could be causing it

Comment: Compile your program with debug information and use a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem to my own question.

I removed the destructor and the error statement is gone.

```
BinaryHeap::~BinaryHeap() //DONE
{   
while (!is_empty())
    v1.pop_back();
}
```

I am not sure why because all I got was "I will not debug your program" and that is fine, but if you would like to know the reason this error has occurred you will have to look elsewhere, as I received no answer as to why this could be happening.